# Best Way to Archive R files for Thesis

Tags: r

I am close to finish my master thesis. And during this time I got a lot of `.R` files. Some are simply trial and error and some are more serious. I would like to archive all my stuff so that my graders can access them if they want to and also that I can use them in the future if needed. What is the best format in R to achieve this goal, please? Is `R` project something worth trying? Thank you!

Comment: How many files are we talking about here?

Comment: why not just store them on github?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Between 20 and 30 files. Perhaps not that many. The thing I would like to do is to make them more integrated.

Comment: For the purpose of making the (published) calculations in your thesis reproducible, I would recommend taking a single backup of all R files maybe in a ZIP file.  You can also use Git/GitHub if you want to make them easily available to others.

Comment: depends on the thesis but if it makes sense for readers to be able to see the code, then include it in the appendix -- if it's pages and pages of code, then so be it. this is the best way to ensure that the entirety of your thesis is properly preserved over time.

Comment: @lispHK01 probably has the best suggestion. Be sure to include version information (R, operating system, packages) as well, if you're going to be so formal about it. and please (for the love of god) comment your code if you're going to take the time to put it in your paper.

Comment: I'm currently looking into this myself, but I think Packrat from RStudio is a good thing to try. It takes a snapshot of all the packages used, so future updates won't break your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a great question and I wish more academics would plan for this. I recommend putting it on github as this is the most common way to share code in the numerical computing community these days. Including it in your thesis would also be good, but honestly it will be much easier for people to use if it is on github.

**Sharing whatever you have is better than sharing nothing**, because people can see what you did. **If you have more time to make it nicer**, I would suggest:

1. Documenting for clarity
2. Removing extraneous code and keeping only that which pertains to your thesis
3. For each specific result in your thesis, provide a specific script that generates that result. If you have figures, provide a script that generates that exact figure.

This is what I did for the Python code I used to analyze data in my paper published in an academic journal. This way, anybody who reads the paper and is unclear about the findings or how I generated them, can take a look at the code and see exactly how the analysis was performed. Here is the github repository I created for this:
https://github.com/cxrodgers/Rodgers2014

To ensure reproducibility, it's best to also document the versions of the modules or software packages (e.g., R) that you used, or even to copy them into your software repository as well.

Comment: I think documenting the r version used as well as packages version numbers is important as well. Packages get pulled from CRAN so a backup of them some where would be good also.